# Non renewable in app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Now I'm working with **Non Renewable In-App Purchases**. I have several questions for you guys.

User1 buy the subscription to 1 month, for example. I save expiration date of subscription in my backend. Everything is ok, but after 1 month User1 wants to re-buy subscription. But apple will say: "User1, you bought it before, lets make a restore" and extends his subscription expiration date.

1. How can I solve that problem?
2. How can I control expiration date of subscription?

Comment: You mentioned that "User1 wants to re-buy subscription", so what about letting it an auto renewable purchase (Auto-Renewable Subscription)?

Comment: That isn't how non-renewing subscriptions work. They are more like a consumable; The user can purchase them multiple times.  Your app should ensure that you only allow the user to purchase a new subscription when the current period has expired (or is about to) and it is your responsibility to determine the new expiration date.  Non-renewing subscriptions cannot be restored through the IAP process.